# Issues connecting from SQL Server to MS Access database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Environment: Windows Server 2016, SQL Server 2016; MS Access `.accdb` files (various versions)

Attempting to establish a linked server via oledb to an `.accdb` file content like this:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
            @server = N'redacted',
            @srvproduct = N'',
            @provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
            @datasrc = N'D:\AccessTest\redacted.accdb',
            @provstr = N'Jet OLEDB:Database Password=redacted;'
```

This causes an error:

> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "redacted" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399)

Attempted fixes:

- Varying provider strings, like 'Uid=*;Pwd=*'
- Check AccessDB engine is installed (64bit)
- Moved db to local drive (from network)
- OLE provider set 'Allow Inprocess' to true

The database appears to be accessible through MS Access front end. No signs of corruption.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just an idea, try:  `@srvproduct='Access',
@provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
`

Comment: I do not believe there is a `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` but `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

Comment: @Parfait these correspond to releases of MS Access.  They are advertised to be backwards compatible.  I have and have tried versions 12 .  You can grab version 16 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: @sniperd I do not see that provider listed but I will see if I can dig it up and let you know how it goes.  I suspect this problem revolves around SQL server account permissions.

Comment: @AlexanderToptygin ... I have been working in MS Access for quite a while. 2016 is not the same as `OLDEB.16.0`. Check the *Install Instructions* of your very link mentioning `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` to be used for OLEDB. This handles Access .accdb files (2007-2016). The other `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` is for older .mdb files (<=2003).